# Extract elements from a particular list on python

Tags: python, json, list, extract, element

Here is the block to analyse:

```
('images\\Principales\\Screenshot_1.png', '{"categories":[{"name":"abstract_","score":0.00390625},{"name":"outdoor_","score":0.01171875},{"name":"outdoor_road","score":0.41796875}],"description":{"tags":["road","building","outdoor","scene","street","city","sitting","empty","light","view","driving","red","sign","intersection","green","large","riding","traffic","white","tall","blue","fire"],"captions":[{"text":"a view of a city street","confidence":0.83864323826716347}]},"requestId":"73fc14d5-653f-4a0a-a45a-e7a425580361","metadata":{"width":150,"height":153,"format":"Png"},"color":{"dominantColorForeground":"Grey","dominantColorBackground":"Grey","dominantColors":["Grey"],"accentColor":"274A68","isBWImg":false}}')
```

I need to extract all elements after "description", but i don't know how to do that... (in fact, i need this elements:

```
"road", "building","outdoor","scene","street","city","sitting","empty","light","view","driving","red","sign","intersection","green","large","riding","traffic","white","tall","blue","fire"
```

I've been looking for several minutes already, but I do not understand how to do it! I'm a little beginner in learning "lists" element, and I still have a hard time understanding.

The "For" loop returns only `'images\\Principales\\Screenshot_1.png'`, then the big blocks left ...

Did you have a solution?

Thanks in advence!

**EDIT:**

Indeed, it is actually JSON! Thanks to the people who helped me :)
To extract the desired elements contained in the second block, I simply proceeded thus:

```
import json
ElementSeparate= '{"categories":[{"name":"abstract_","score":0.00390625},{"name":"outdoor_","score":0.01171875},{"name":"outdoor_road","score":0.41796875}],"description":{"tags":["road","building","outdoor","scene","street","city","sitting","empty","light","view","driving","red","sign","intersection","green","large","riding","traffic","white","tall","blue","fire"],"captions":[{"text":"a view of a city street","confidence":0.83864323826716347}]},"requestId":"73fc14d5-653f-4a0a-a45a-e7a425580361","metadata":{"width":150,"height":153,"format":"Png"},"color":{"dominantColorForeground":"Grey","dominantColorBackground":"Grey","dominantColors":["Grey"],"accentColor":"274A68","isBWImg":false}'
ElementSeparate = json.loads(ElementSeparate)
for a in ElementSeparate['description']['tags']:
    print a
```

Comment: The second element - the big blog - is a string. Looks like it is JSON, you could probably parse it with `json.loads()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like you're trying to parse JSON.  You should use the JSON parser for the second element of the array.  You'll get back either list or dictionary.  Then you'll be able to extract data from "description" key has.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: Thank you very much :( I'm ashamed, thank you for giving me on the right way! I understand better my mistake, I would search more next time

Comment: We all have to start somewhere don't be discouraged!